# Simplify test configuration by reading App.config from tests

Tags: c#

My app allows the user to specify in App.config the columns they want in their output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>

  .
  .
  .
  <!-- specify columns you want -->
  <add key="NameCol" value="true"/>
  <add key="AddressCol" value="true"/>
  <add key="TelCol" value="true"/>
  .
  .
  .
 </appSettings>
```

I have a separate project that tests my app. In the tests I change various column settings and  after each test clear the settings using code like this:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
// set config options here

// now clear config options
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("NameCol");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("AddressCol");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("TelCol");
```

Is there a way to read the column names from the App.config file and have a for loop for the above? So it would be something like this. What would getColNamesFromAppConfig() looklike?

```
columnNames = getColNamesFromAppConfig()
foreach (string colName in ColumnNames)
{
  config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(colName);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
    foreach (SettingsProperty property in Settings.Properties) // or ConfigurationProperty? 
    {
        // ...
    }
```

PS. By the way, if I were you, I would consider wrapping settings in a custom object (implemented by yourself). If you have to do this:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("NameCol");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("AddressCol");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("TelCol");
```

in a test, it's a code smell to me. I believe you should be able to mock settings for testing purposes. This is a matter of taste, however.